# OpenSourceMANO is failed after restart host

Tags: virtual-machine, openstreetmap

I have installed opensourcemano(release:13, OS:Ubuntu 20.04 server) on a VM. After restart VM, the osm does not well. I repeated this operation on Windows VMware WorkStation and CentOS8 Virtual Manager.

- For Windows VMware Workstation case, the web interface of osm is displayed, but I cant login because of mongodb error.
- For CentOS8 Virtual Manager case, all the core containers of osm are not running. Only Kubernetes-related containers are active. Of course, web interface is not displayed.

What is the reason?

My purpose is that after rebooting the host vm, ensure the osm works well.
And for the cloud image generation, generate a OSM qcow2 image file.
How can I do it?